# build folder missing in Finder on Mac after npm build

Tags: macos, npm, finder

After running `npm run-script build` the `build` folder is not visible in Mac Finder.

But the folder is there, as seen via Terminal window `ls` command.

How can I get the folder to display in finder?

Answer (score 2):

1. **The `build` folder might be hidden.** You can try pressing <kbd>cmd + shift + .</kbd> in Finder to turn on showing hidden folders.
2. **You might have opened Finder in the wrong folder.**  Try running `open .` in the terminal where you ran `ls` in.  That will open Finder in the correct folder.

Comment: @GregLafrance did this help at all?  If so, please accept the answer to indicate that.